# Picking one of many identical rows with certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

To set the scene, what I define as identical rows are when the combination of destination and vehicle_brand are the same. For instance in the figure below,

[SQL table name: cardriven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CrTp.png)

rows 2 and 3 are "identical" because of the Dallas-Toyota "combination." Now I want to only display the row with the higher request_id. So for example, between rows 2 and 3, row 3 would get displayed and row 2 would be hidden/removed because 169 > 100. So in the end, only rows 3, 4, 5, 7, and 8 will show and rows 1, 2, 6, and 9 would get hidden/removed.

Hopefully you understand what I am going for here but if you have any questions, please let me know. This will be written in SQL code.

Another problem: I added a new column for dates and entered some random ones for rows 2-4. Row 2 is 12/1/17, row 3 is 11/5/2016, and row 4 is 7/6/2017. Note that row 3 has the highest request_id out of the Dallas-Toyota combination. I decided to enter a new entry in with a request_id = 501 and entry of Dallas, Toyota, and 12/22/2017. After running the program, for Dallas-Toyota I return row 3 but with request_id = 501! It SHOULD return the entry I just entered.

Comment: Look into what the [`ROW_NUMBER()` window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) does. You'll want to partition by destination and vehicle_brand and order by request_id desc, then select only the rows where the row number is 1.

Comment: @ZLK Ok understand what you mean with ROW_NUMBER() but not with what you mean by partition and everything after.

Comment: Congratulations on your first post! I'm glad you found your answer. In the future it's helpful if you can include queries that you tried but failed as it helps tell the story more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group By and the Max function to get the highest value.

```
SELECT MAX(request_id), destination, vehicle_brand
FROM cardriven
GROUP BY destination, vehicle_brand
```

Comment: Then how do I delete all the other rows that are not the highest? You forgot to add that part in.

Comment: the Group By will remove any row that doesn't have the highest id.

Comment: For me that didn't happen.

Comment: I have come across a problem

Comment: I added a new column for dates and entered some random ones for rows 2-4. Row 2 is 12/1/17, row 3 is 11/5/2016, and row 4 is 7/6/2017. Note that row 3 has the highest request_id out of the Dallas-Toyota combination. I decided to enter a new entry in with a request_id = 501 and entry of Dallas, Toyota, and 12/22/2017. After running the program, for Dallas-Toyota I return row 3 but with request_id = 501! It SHOULD return the entry I just entered.

Comment: I will give you the check mark to get the 25 points. I would just like some help on this.

Comment: Can you add the current record list to your question so we can see how it looks now.